# Activate pgAdmin 4 desktop mode

Tags: pgadmin-4

I have downloaded PostgreSQL 10.4 and when I launch it pgAdmin4 opens in a web browser. I want to use the desktop mode and I don't know how to do it on Windows 7.
Any help ?

Comment: I would't now pgAdmin to have a "desktop mode" nor a "web mode" (the latter being pointless anyway, as it would need to install a web server somewhere, which would need access to the database.) It is just a desktop application. What's the URL it opens? And what do you see when you do a right click on the link, choosing "Properties" in the "General" tab?

Comment: https://image.ibb.co/chKQ8J/pwxcwxc.jpg

Comment: @stickybit: pgAdmin 4 is indeed a web application, and yes it starts a local web server for that. Pretty annoying

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Yes, in deed. The time I posted the comment I only new the old version of pgAdmin 4 which was no web application then. I just recently found out, that they switched to a web application (and am desperately trying to get [pgAdmin 3 LTS](https://www.openscg.com/bigsql/pgadmin3/) to run... but that's another story...).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pgAdmin 4 always open in browser not as a standalone desktop application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435656/pgadmin-4-always-open-in-browser-not-as-a-standalone-desktop-application)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905092/877099

Answer (score 18):

Latest non-web desktop version was v2.1 https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v2.1/windows/

Since v3.0 they completely moved to browser version

Comment: Here is described how to start new browser window with new icon for pgAdmin: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905092/877099

Comment: ouch. i hate browser apps for editors because they can't do a lot of shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.

**Download PgAdmin III - it's separate query editor**
[official link v1.22.2/win32](https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin3/v1.22.2/win32/)