# pgadmin4 Ver 3.0 not starting on windows 10

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

for a PostgreSQL project I installed pgadmin 4 Ver. 3.0 on a Windows 10 computer.
Anyhow pgadmin does not start and I get the following error from the Internet Explorer Browser:
"Cannot reach this page. Make sure the web address http://127.0.0.1:56575 is correct.".

I've been using PgAdmin 4 Ver 2.1 for some time without issues, and have uninstalled it before installing the Ver 3.0.
Any help would be appreciated.
Regards,

Comment: Please follow up and let us know if you were able to resolve the problem somehow.

Comment: Using Chrome it worked, but not with Internet Explorer.Anyhow I haven't tried anymore using I.E.with pgadmin so I can't tell whether the actual version is now working with IE.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the update. By the way, for anyone who prefers to run the client in a dedicated window, Chrome now supports that.  Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905092/3303195

Answer (score 0):

For PGadmin 4 Ver 3.0 you need to completely start afresh. Remove any old shortcuts and make a new one. You need to locate where PGadmin was installed and make a new shortcut with a target and path like ""C:\Program Files (x86)\pgAdmin 4\v3\runtime\pgAdmin4.exe".
For anyone else viewing this, make sure you do an uninstall of the old PGadmin before installing the new one.
Further, you may not be able to get an SQL window running unless you allow it through addblockers etc

Comment: I have tried all available suggestions without succes, on another laptop where Chrome is the default browser it seems to work, on my current laptop I have to use IE. At the moment I returned back to Ver 2.1.
It is not clear whether stopping the pgadmin 4 process as indicated in another thread might have caused the problems.

Comment: I think you can log PGadmin issues here;
https://redmine.postgresql.org/projects/pgadmin4/issues