# How to start pgAdmin 4 as a desktop app on Linux?

Tags: pgadmin-4

I've just managed to launch pgAdmin 4 on my OpenSuSE Leap 15.0 Linux (x86_64) machine, but it would always appear in a Firefox tab. I would like to run it as a desktop app, though. I've found a clue on how to do this in [question #50435656, answer #3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435656/pgadmin-4-always-open-in-browser-not-as-a-standalone-desktop-application), but  apparently this applies to Windows only (taskbar icon…). So: How do I re-config pgAdmin4 on Linux so that it will start in the look & feel of a desktop app? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I've found it out after reading the [corresponding section of the pgAdmin 4 doc](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/3.x/server_deployment.html#configuration): You've gotta open the user-specifig config file `~/.config/pgadmin/pgadmin4.conf` and then define the corresponding entry as follows:

```
BrowserCommand=/usr/bin/google-chrome --app=%URL%
```

pgAdmin4 will then start in a stand-alone Google Chrome window.