# DBevear doesn't show the detailed database view

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I have a detailed view of the database when I use the PgAdmin in OS X:

[image]

However, all the properties like functions, procedures, etc don't available from the DBevear app and only see the tables for the respective schema:

[image]

I have to remove and re-installed the app again to the system and it doesn't help.

How do I fix this and if not possible, what are the alternatives that I can use instead of DBvear?

Comment: I personally prefer pgAdmin over DBevear. You can also use DataGrip by jetBrains if you can afford a license :)

Comment: pgAdmin is fine but it works in the browser and I prefer to use a desktop app. I have a license for the Jetbrain, so I will try the DataGrip as suggested.

Comment: DataGrip is faster and have a lot of tools... For pgAdmin it can be ran as an app by following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52905092/6150881

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a setting in your connection-settings, so right click on "billing -localhost" (the connection to the db) choose "edit connection" -> general  ->navigator view -> set it to advanced

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems I can't find it. If you have access to the DBvear, can you also add a screenshot? Thank you.

Comment: rightclick the elephant with the green checker, not the db sign